# push для ассоциативного массива или как отправить массив

Tags: php, javascript

Есть категории, к примеру их 2 и записи к ним
вывожу так

```
<div id="list">
    <div id="cat">test</div><div id="record">1123</div>
    <div id="cat">test2</div><div id="record">2232</div>
    <div id="cat">test2</div><div id="record">3123</div>
    <div id="cat">test</div><div id="record">3223</div>
</div>
```

как их собрать и отправить POSTом чтобы результат был такой?

```
<?
Array
(
    [1123] => test
    [2232] => test2
    [3123] => test2
    [3223] => test
)
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Такое чувство что в вопросе пропущен тег jquery :-)

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```js
$(function() {
  var result = {},
      value = false;

  $("#list").find("div").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this), id = $this.attr("id");

    if (id == "cat") value = $this.text();
    else if (id == "record" && value) {
      result[$this.text()] = value;
      value = false;
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413219/script.php", // :-)
    data: result
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="list">
    <div id="cat">test</div><div id="record">1123</div>
    <div id="cat">test2</div><div id="record">2232</div>
    <div id="cat">test2</div><div id="record">3123</div>
    <div id="cat">test</div><div id="record">3223</div>
</div>
```

Ну а внутри script.php в $_POST будет лежать:

```
Array (
    [1123] => test
    [2232] => test2
    [3123] => test2
    [3223] => test
)
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP преобразует переменные из URL в массивы, если они имеют имя типа `foo[]`. Соответственно, ваш запрос должен выглядеть:

http://example.com/index.php?a[1123]=test&a[2232]=test2&a[3123]=test2&a[3223]=test

Если ключи или значения могут содержать произвольные символы, то не забудьте использовать `encodeURIComponent`:

```js
... + "a[" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "]=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + ...
```

В самом скрипте вы можете получить значение в виде `$_GET['a']` — оно будет содержать требуемый вам массив.

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что у Вас значение `id` повторяется (Это какой-то `xml`? Не вижу даже намека). Попробуйте использовать вместо `id` - `class`, это будет универсально:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="cat">test</div><div class="record">1123</div>
    <div class="cat">test2</div><div class="record">2232</div>
    <div class="cat">test2</div><div class="record">3123</div>
    <div class="cat">test</div><div class="record">3223</div>
</div>
```

"сборку" тоже можно сделать достаточно очевидной (с `jquery`):

```
var result = {};
$("#list div.cat").each(function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    var key = $this.next( 'div.record' ).text();
    result[key] = $this.text();
} );
```